# Getting error after upgrading the joomla site and admin end is blank page

Tags: joomla

After upgrading the joomla site iam getting the following error and administrator page is blank.
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/cll/public_html/libraries/regularlabs/src/File.php on line 283
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Joomla questions are welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Disable the plugin in the database but better to ask at the joomla exchange because this is not a programming question, it's a using Joomla question.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that the problem comes from a regularlabs extension so you should disable it.
Since your admin page is blank, you can do this via the file system. Log in to your FTP account (or use the control panel's file manager) and access your root folder (/home/cll/public_html/). The extension you are looking for is probably a plugin so you'll find it in the plugins folder. I assume you'll find the extension in the /plugins/system/ folder (full path: /home/cll/public_html/plugins/system/).
When you'll find the extension's folder look for the plugin's PHP file and rename it.
For example, if the problem comes from "components anywhere" plugin (it's a regularlabs extension) search for componentsanywhere.php and rename it to something else (eg foobar.php).
If this doesn't help contact the developer to help you, he is a good guy.

Comment: Probably if you are in a control panel better to go to the database and change it to disabled.